# Description in 'Share on facebook' is missed up

Tags: facebook, share

I just added a new buttons for sharing contents of my posts on blogger using this code that I installed afer `<data:post.body/>` :

```
    <!-- AddThis Button BEGIN -->
<div class="addthis_toolbox addthis_default_style addthis_16x16_style">
<a class="addthis_button_facebook" title="Facebook"></a>
<a class="addthis_button_twitter" title="Twitter"></a>
<a class="addthis_button_email" title="e-mail"></a>
<a class="addthis_button_print" title="Imprimer"></a>
<a class="addthis_button_googlebuzz" title="Buzz"></a>
<a class="addthis_button_google" title="Google"></a>
<a class="addthis_button_favorites" title="Ajouter aux favoris"></a>
<a class="addthis_button_compact"></a>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://s7.addthis.com/js/250/addthis_widget.js#pubid=xa-4dedda0c245832a7"></script>
<!-- AddThis Button END -->
```

The problem is that when I want to share it on facebook, Description show other element like a sort of an 'html' code on it ! I tried to fix with the previous questions posted here but it didn't work !
Here you can see it when you share : http://scheissemag.blogspot.com/2011/06/this-summers-faux-pas.html

Comment: @matt ball Faceebook sharing under the post !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the `<head />` tag, add this:

```
 <meta property="og:description" content="Your description"/>
```

Alternatively, you can set this:

```
<meta name="description" content="Your description" />
```

You should be setting the second one anyways for SEO purposes.  If you implement this and you don't see the change apply, use Facebook's [linter](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/lint/) tool to refresh their cache.